# ActiveX sandboxed from hardware? Alternatives?

Tags: c#, asp.net, activex, internet-explorer-11

I'm in a bit of a pickle. The company I am working for is developing a website in ASP .NET MVC that involves a professional grade USB scanner on the client side. With Silverlight, it was easy to access the scanner from the app. However, since silverlight is deprecated, my boss wants to move on to another technology. Our biometric SDK is in C#, so ActiveX was the obvious choice (aside from it being hilariously old, unsupported in nearly every browser, and horribly insecure... Can you tell it wasn't my idea?)

So far I've been unable to get the ActiveX component to talk to the scanner. Identical code run as a windows application works fine, but when run as an activex applet it doesn't seem to recognize the device is connected. So my question is does IE 11/ActiveX sandbox the ActiveX component from USB devices? Is it possible to speak on a hardware level and maybe I'm missing something? Is there a reasonable alternative to this ancient framework?

Comment: Dude, you're screwed, I've been in a similar position and there's nothing (at least that I know) you can do to make it work from web. We finished creating a very little service which the user installed on the machine and listened for a websocket connection, then from the page we connected to the local service through the websocket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an idea - there may be other (possibly better) solutions.

You can try creating a desktop application so you can access the device easily and then host the web browser within the application (WebBrowser Control) for the rest of the web UI. This would allow you to communicate with the device locally and then pass information to the website from the desktop application using a web service API.

This still requires your users to install something locally but it gives you an integrated option. (I'm not 100% sure but I don't think you can do this without a local component and ActiveX is only supported in IE - I'd most definitely avoid that for a lot of reasons.)

You can, of course, just create a local application with whatever UI you need to get data from the scanner and then access the website through an external browser - it's really down to your preference. The WebBrowser control may give you a bit more control over the browser environment but then users may want to access the site from other browsers / devices anyway.

@Gusman's comment is a good alternative, too - at the end, you'll likely have to install something locally.

Comment: This is what I was thinking. My boss is one of those "Web is the future" kind of guys, but I just don't think this problem is solvable using a framework quite literally older than me :) Thanks for the help.